# I want to make code into a function and have it called separately from the form file, but I cant get it to work

Tags: php, html, forms

The aim is to use the php below as a function to edit a record in a form instead of keeping the php in the same file as the form (as it is below).  This code works perfectly fine in the same file, but i wanted to make the php  into a function, and use it from the functions file. This is the problem.

I wanted to tidy up my code, and have functions for everything. My issue is, it just does not work without the code being in the same file as the form when I move it and call it a function.

I have tried various ways but just not sure how to get the form to recognise the $row variable, or $id variables as a function.

```
<?php
    require_once('../db.php');
    $upload_dir = '../uploads';

 //All this php is what I tried to put into a function in a separate 
 file.    
 //The $row variable and $id variable are not recognised unless I leave 
 the php
 //in the same file.
//functions file would use this code and i then made the function using 
 the php below.
 /*     if (isset($_POST['edit_dog_btn'])) {
 **        edit_dog_record();
 */     }

  if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
   $id = $_GET['id'];
   $id=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,trim($_GET['id']));
   echo $id;
   $sql = "SELECT * from contacts where id=".$id;
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
     $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
   }else {
     $errorMsg = 'Could not Find Any Record';
   }
  }

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $age = $_POST['age'];
  $gender = $_POST['gender'];
  $breed = $_POST['breed'];
  $description = $_POST['description'];

   $imgName = $_FILES['image']['name'];   
   $imgTmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
   $imgSize = $_FILES['image']['size'];

  if($imgName){
   $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
   $allowExt  = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif');
   $userPic = time().'_'.rand(1000,9999).'.'.$imgExt;
   if(in_array($imgExt, $allowExt)){
 if($imgSize < 5000000){
    unlink($upload_dir.$row['image']);
         move_uploaded_file($imgTmp ,$upload_dir.$userPic);
      }else{
    $errorMsg = 'Image too large';
        }
     }else{
    $errorMsg = 'Please select a valid image';
     }
    }else{

        $userPic = $row['image'];
    }

    if(!isset($errorMsg)){
        $sql = "update contacts set name = '".$name."',
        age = '".$age."',
                gender = '".$gender."',
                breed= '".$breed."',
                description= '".$description."',                                         
                image = '".$userPic."'
        where id=".$id;
       $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
       if($result){
        $successMsg = 'New record updated successfully';
        header('Location:index_admin.php');
        }else{
            $errorMsg = 'Error '.mysqli_error($conn);
        }
        }

    }

   ?>


   //I think something else is required in the form, in order to use the 
  function //as a separate file. 
 <form class="" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="name">Name</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"  placeholder="Enter 
   Name" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
 </div>
   <div class="form-group">
   <label for="age">Age:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="age" placeholder="Enter 
     Age" value="<?php echo $row['age']; ?>">
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
  <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="gender" placeholder="Enter 
  Gender" value="<?php echo $row['gender']; ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="breed">Breed</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="breed" 
         placeholder="Enter Breed" value="<?php echo $row['breed']; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="description">Breed</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" 
       placeholder="Enter a Description" value="<?php echo 
        $row['description']; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="image">Choose Image</label>
       <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="<?php echo $upload_dir.$row['image'] ?>" width="100">
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" value="">
         </div>
          </div>
         <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" name="edit_dog_btn" class="btn btn-primary 
         waves">Submit</button>
         </div>
    </form>
```

any help would be appreciated, the errors I have been getting are that the varables row and id are not recognised in the form file.

I may just leave it as it is if I can't figure it out today and try again another time but would be great to know how to do it as I have a similar function to add a record and it works fine.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.  You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

When using a function, we need to pass arguments to it.  I suspect from your question that you are very nearly there but may have failed to pass the arguments into it.

In the form page, all the variables are available to the function processes, but when you call a function from another page, the function has no variables to work with unless you pass these as function arguments.

Inline code such as your example may look like this...

```
 $drink = "coffee";

 echo $drink;
```

This would echo the word coffee.  But if we were to create a function elsewhere and call it, we could write it like this;

```
function outputDrink() {
    echo $drink;
}
```

and we could call it in our page as follows;

```
$drink = "coffee";
outputDrink();
```

But this would display nothing... as $drink isnt being passed into the function.  To rectify this we need some amendements;

```
   function outputDrink($drink) {
    echo $drink;
}
```

and call it like this

```
$drink = "coffee";
outputDrink($drink);
```

Finally, if we need more to pass more information we can pass an array or comma separate our values.  Indeed we can set default values and much more.  But perhaps those options are better for another answer.

Good Luck.

Comment: thanks.. will need to study this functionality a bit more. Still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the arguments into your function.

```
if (isset($_POST['edit_dog_btn'])) {
         edit_dog_record($arg1, $arg2, ...);
}
```

This way, the variables will be available to your function. Since it is on a different page, it doesn't just have access to the values.

```
function edit_dog_record($arg1, $arg2){
   //you can use $arg1 and $arg2 now
}
```